# Accessing Github environment variables in custom Github Action

Tags: github-actions

I'm writing my own Docker Github Action and I need access to some Github environment variable, specifically to the [GITHUB_WORKSPACE](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/environment-variables#default-environment-variables) variable.

I assume the user has called the [checkout@v2](https://github.com/actions/checkout) action beforehand and in my `action.yml` the run section looks as follows

```
runs:
  using: 'docker'
  image: 'Dockerfile'
  args:
    - ${{ github.workspace }}
```

But I get the following error

> Unrecognized named-value: 'github'. Located at position 1 within
> expression: github.workspace

How do I make the supposedly globally available Github environment variables accessible from my action?

Comment: This seems like a huge bug in actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to do anything.

[These variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/environment-variables#default-environment-variables) are available directly in the container (in your action). They are injected by GitHub.
In the action.yaml you do **not** need to specify anything and you can then access them in you code.

Note: The input values are also injected, but they start with `INPUT_` and are capitalized.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - where is the part about `INPUT_` is documented?

Comment: It is referenced in the docs for [metadata syntax](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#example)

Comment: Can you add an example of the original action code properly accessing the `github.workspace` variable?

Comment: I need to be able to access these variables specifically in the args so that I can add logic such as: `- ${{ github.ref != 'refs/heads/main' && '--dry-run' }}` Is there no way to actually access the `github` variable in the args?